# Converting CSV file to SQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have successfully written a php file that convert a csv file to sql and writes it to the database. See below:

```html
<?php

  $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

  mysql_select_db("fmd", $conn);

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $handle = fopen($file,"r");

    while (($fileop = fgetcsv($handle, 100000, ",")) !== false) {
      $Work_Request_Code = $fileop[0];
      $Building_Code = $fileop[1];
      $Floor_Code = $fileop[2];
      $Room_Code = $fileop[3];
      $Work_Description = $fileop[4];
      $Date_Work_Requested = $fileop[5];
      $Primary_Trade_Required = $fileop[6];
      $Problem_Type = $fileop[7];
      $Work_Request_Status = $fileop[8];
      $Requested_by = $fileop[9];

      $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO work_requests (Work_Request_Code, Building_Code, Floor_Code, Room_Code, Work_Description, Date_Work_Requested, Primary_Trade_Required, Problem_Type, Work_Request_Status, Requested_by) VALUES ('$Work_Request_Code','$Building_Code','$Floor_Code','$Room_Code','$Work_Description','$Date_Work_Requested','$Primary_Trade_Required','$Problem_Type','$Work_Request_Status','$Requested_by')");
    }

    if($sql){
      echo "Done!";
    }
  }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SQL Converter</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mainWrapper">
    <form method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I know my csv file has 21527 records but the mysql query only goes through 19020 records. I added a count variable, and I was able to conclude that the while loop is indeed looping through all record.

I am not sure why this is happening.

Comment: any unique fields defined in the table, preventing from duplicates to enter?

Comment: I can't even remember when this archaic, insecure API was deprecated

Comment: @GuyL no unique fields defined in the table

Comment: @Strawberry what are you suggesting?

Comment: The recommendation is to stop using all `mysql_` functions and start using `mysqli_` or pdo.  How many of your values have apostrophes in them?  I further recommend prepared statements for stability.  Any bad news in your error log? We expect you to check your error log before posting a debugging question on this site.

Comment: Your comment flag has been declined. Please read about [how to flag comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373801/when-is-a-comment-hostile-or-unfriendly-educating-newer-users-how-to-flag-comm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a unique field in your table. At first glance, it could be the `Work_Request_Code`. Since this is also the first field in your CSV, it's easy to check if you have duplicates.

```
cut -d, -f1 FILENAME | sort | uniq -d
```

If you have any duplicate `Work_Request_Code`, it will be output by this command.

BUT: you are not escaping the strings you stick into your query! You should really use the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) interface! If for some reason this is not possible, then you should at least change your lines of code where you fetch the data form the CSV array like this (I'll do it only for the first element):

```
$Work_Request_Code = mysql_escape_string($fileop[0]);
```

If you don't escape your strings, a single quote in your data will break your query, and if you don't stop when `mysql_query` returns `false` (and don't look at your logs), all queries containing single quotes will be effectively skipped. Try

```
grep "'" FILENAME | wc -l
```

It might return exactly the number of missing entries.

Comment: I used MySQLi and the problem is still there. In addition, Work_Request_Code does not have any duplicate values.

Comment: have you tried the last command chain? Does it return `2507`?

Comment: You are correct! I did what you said and I found out the missing entries. Afterwards I went to look at the data to see if there were any single quotation and indeed there were single quotations on all the missing entries. In my 5th column (Work_Description) single quotation was used such as "John's room". Thank you!